# Inexpected segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a Trie for storing phone numbers. While doing so I would to count the number of nodes needed to store all the different numbers.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Node{
    public:
        char number;
        vector<Node*> followings;

        Node(){
        number = ' ';
    }
        Node(char n){
        number = n;
        followings.resize(10);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int N;
    cin >> N; cin.ignore();
    Node aux(' ');
    Node* root = &aux;
    Node* node;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        string telephone;
        cin >> telephone; cin.ignore();
    node = root;
        for(int j = 0; j < telephone.size(); j++){
            if(node->followings[(int)telephone[j]-48]->number == ' '){
                Node aux(telephone[j]);
                node->followings[(int)telephone[j]-48] = &aux;
        counter++;

            }
            node = node->followings[(int)telephone[j]-48];
        }
    }

    cout << counter << endl;
}
```

However I get a segmentation fault when trying to access the number of a node `node->followings[(int)telephone[j]-48]->number`. Does anyone know why I'm gettint that error and how to fix it?

Thanks you in advance
I'm a little bit new to C++

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`) and perhaps [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Your fix-my-code question is off-topic.

Comment: Because `followings` is a vector of nullptrs, thus `->number` segfaults.

Comment: `telephone[j]-'0'` is portable, but `telephone[j]-48` isn't.

Comment: Whe do you have expected segmentation faults?

Answer (score 2):

You are resizing `following` but then it contains the default value of components, that is `nullptr` (so any access to them is segfaulting). You probably should replace `followings.resize(10);` with `followings.reserve(10);`

You should use somewhere `following->push_back(someptr)` with `somptr` being a point to an *allocated* `Node`.

You probably should use [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), perhaps [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) e.g. `std::unique_ptr<Node>` as the type of the components in `followings`

Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`) and perhaps [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).